# checking if a field is empty in jquery(js)?

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, input

If a field is empty when it is blurred (loses focus) I want to remove an image:

Here's the beginning code:

```
$('#type').keyup(function(){
   $('#image').show();

 $("#type").blur( function() {

// i wanted to check here if #type field is empty as well before hiding?

        $('#image').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#type").blur( function() {
  if (this.value === '') {
    $('#image').hide();
  }
});
```